# rendering confusionmatrix using Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Got 3 predictive models and took the predictions to compose a matrix using every model predictions to populate a columns.

predictions.rda

```
target;ctree;gbm;svm

a;a;a;b

b;b;b;c

c;a;c;c
```

Saved as **rda** file, and I'm trying to load some confusion matrices using shiny. The user must choose one of the models and the page must render the output from the loaded model matrix.

#### ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("MODELS"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput(inputId = "model",
             label = "choose Model:",
            choices = c("Conditional Inference Tree" = "predictions$ctree",
                        "Gradient Boosting Machine" = "predictions$gbm",
                        "Suppor Vector Machine" = "predictions$svm"
                  ),
                  selected = "predictions$ctree")

       ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("matrix")
    )
  )
))
```

#### server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  require(caret)
  load(predictions.rda)

  output$matrix <- renderPrint({

# this line worked fine
# confusionMatrix(predictions$target,predictions$ctree)

#this line does not work
confusionMatrix(predictions$target,input$model)

  })

})
```

The output is:

> Error: the data cannot have more levels than the reference.

Comment: Does it work outside of Shiny?

Comment: Yes. Even if you write predictions$ctree instead input$model it worked fine

Comment: I am facing the same issue, but the problem is that confusionmatrix() output is not character or a dataframe, but a "confusionmatrix" so it would need to be rendered with another method, maybe best way is a piece wise method?